# MYSQL select 3 results of each "page id"

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables... the first is a page list with (page_id, page_title) rows.  The second is a list of items ON those pages each with a price (item_id, page_id, item_title, item_price).

I'd like to grab the top three items from each page (ordered by highest item_price first) with the page having the cumulatively highest price ordered first.  This is quite beyond my MYSQL abilities and I'm looking for advice on how to make this the most efficient! :)  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get the top 3 items for all pages all at once, or one page at a time?

Comment: I want to output a list of all the pages, showing the top three items of each page (top being highest price, and the pages ordered by the cumulative highest price).  Thanks!

Comment: Given an item, how do you know to what page it belongs to?

Comment: Should have included that... my bad -- each item has a "page_id" as well, so we know which page the item is on.  I'll edit the original post.

Comment: So if I'm first looking to grab all the pages in the proper order, is it possible to do something like this?

`SELECT pages.* FROM pages, items WHERE pages.id == items.page_id ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(SELECT items.item_price FROM items WHERE items.page_id==pages.id ORDER BY items.item_price LIMIT 0,3))`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a few different ways. What I would do is run one query that says "get me all pages ordered by the sum total of their items" then loop through them in php, and for each one, do a "get me the top 3 items for the current page".

Make sense?

Query one (untested, written on my phone):

```
SELECT p.page_name, (SELECT SUM(item_price) FROM items WHERE page_id = p.page_id) AS cumulative_price FROM pages p ORDER BY cumulative_price DESC;
```

Query two (also untested) looping through results of query one:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE page_id = '$currentPageId' ORDER BY item_price DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Obviously you would include the page id in the first query for use in the second.

Answer (score 0):

- I'm assuming every page_id is equal to item_id, and that's how they're linked together. (If not, please correct me.)
- I'm just going to call the second table "table2" and the item_id I'm looking up "SOME_ITEM_ID"

  ```
  SELECT * FROM `table2` WHERE `item_id` = 'SOME_ITEM_ID' ORDER BY `item_price` DESC;
  ```

In English what this is saying is:

Select everything from table2 where the item_id is ***this***, and order the list by item_price in descending order

This SQL statement will return every hit, but you would just output the first three in your code.

Comment: My bad here - I edited the original post.  The items table is linked to the pages table via a "page_id".  Items have both an "item_id" and a "page_id".

Answer (score 0):

My gut tells me that there is probably no *faster* way to do this than to do a for-loop in the application over all of the pages, doing a little `select item_price from item where page_id = ? order by item_price desc limit 3` for each paqe, and possibly sticking the results in something like memcached so you aren't taxing your database too much.

But I like a challenge, so i'll attempt it anyhow.

```
SELECT p1.*, i1.*,
 (SELECT count(*)
  FROM items i2
  WHERE i1.item_price < i2.item_price
  AND p1.page_id = i2.page_id) price_rank,
FROM pages p1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN items i1 
 ON p1.page_id = i1.page_id
WHERE price_rank < 3;
```

That odd sub-select is going to probably do an awful lot of work for every single row in `items`.  many other RDBMses have a feature called window functions that can do the above much more elegantly.  For instance, if you were using PostgreSQL, you could have written:

```
SELECT p1.*, i1.*, 
    RANK(i1.item_price) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY p1.page_id
          ORDER BY i1.item_price DESC) price_rank 
FROM pages p1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN items i1 
 ON p1.page_id = i1.page_id
WHERE price_rank <= 3;
```

And the planner would have arranged to visit rows in an order that results in the rank occurring properly.